# How to save data to xampp phpmyadmin mysql database from windows form application c#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, connection

How to save data  to xampp phpmyadmin mysql database from windows form application c# ? variables with data are country1,city1,temperature1.
Database is weather and table is forecast

```
try
{

    string MyConnection2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3307;username=db1;password=db12121";
    string Query = "insert into weather.forecast(country, city, temperature) values('" + country1 + "','" + city1 + "','" + temperature "');";


    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
    MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);
    MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
    MyConn2.Open();
    MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();    
    MessageBox.Show("Save Data");
    while (MyReader2.Read())
    {
    }
    MyConn2.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you:

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection;
        string server = "localhost";
        string database = "weather";
        string uid = "db1";
        string password = "db12121";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    try
        {
            connection.Open();
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into forecast (country,city,temperature) values(@Country,@City,@Temperature)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", country1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temperature", temperature);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMessage.Text = "Database connection failed.";
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        connection.Close();
}
```